# Display a field as a link in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am working on a access application where one of the field is a unique ID number. When I display this field I would like to display it as a URL for example http://www.abc.com/?q=

How I do format a field for display in Access ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display where? On a form? If it is in a `TextBox` on a form then this has the property (in Access 2010) `Display as Hyperlink`, and the possible value `Always`. So take the ID and concatenate the rest of the text:

```
strSome = "http://www.abc.com/?q=" & theID
```

It is also possible in code to manipulate the `Hyperlink` property of a `TextBox` (although I haven't tested this). That is, to create a Hyperlink instance, based on the text in my code-line, set its Address and Sub-Address, and Text to Display properties, then set the TextBox's Hyperlink property to this instance. But, as I say, I haven't had a chance to test this.